# Django admin site, reverse the model association

Tags: django

Right now I have the following models.

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    publisher = models.ManyToManyField(Publisher, related_name='articles', blank=True)
```

When I go to Django admin site -> add/edit Article page, I get the select list of the Article to link.

But when I go to Add/Edit Publisher page I don't see a select list to associate Article

1. How to show Article list in Publisher add/edit page.
2. How to hide Publisher list in Article add/edit page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should implement `ArticleInline` and add it to `PublisherAdmin.inlines`. Check more info about [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)
2. Just add `publisher` to `ArticleAdmin.exclude`